# how can ftp to a hostname fail even though DNS provides the valide ip addr and ftp to the addr succeeds?

Tags: python, tcp, dns, ftp

How is this possible?

```
NodeX# ping ftp.company.com
PING ftp.company.com (xx.yy.8.11) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ftp.company.com (xx.yy.8.11): icmp_seq=1 ttl=127 time=0.657 ms
...
^C
NodeX# /usr/bin/myftp.py -fftp.company.com -uuser -ppasssword 
Transferring myftp.tgz to ftp.company.com:Incoming/
*** ftp login failed: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname
Operation failed, exit code=3
```

Whereas if I do this, it works:

```
NodeX# /usr/bin/myftp.py -fxx.yy.8.11 -uuser -ppassword 
Transferring myftp.tgz to ftp.company.com:Incoming/
Operation completed successfully
```

Also, if I create an entry in /etc/hosts, then it works using the name.  What gives?

Dig shows:

```
NodeX# dig ftp.company.com ANY

; <<>> DiG 9.5.0-P2 <<>> ftp.company.com ANY
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 21125
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ftp.company.com. IN      ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ftp.company.com. 28800 IN A       xx.yy.8.11

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: xx.zz.8.34#53(xx.zz.8.34)
;; WHEN: Thu Oct 11 14:53:00 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 63
```

resolv.conf shows 2 nameservers, a dig @each returns the IP.

Python 2.6 code looks like:

```
    try:
        print("Preparing ftplib.FTP for " + ftpHost)
        ftp = ftplib.FTP()
    except Exception, e:
        print("*** ftp prep failed: %s" % e.__str__())
        return 3
    end
    try:
        print("Connecting to '" + ftpHost + "'")
        ftp.connect(ftpHost, ftpPort)
    except Exception, e:
        print("*** ftp connection failed: %s" % e.__str__())
        return 4
    end
```

Output is:

```
Preparing ftplib.FTP for ftp.company.com
Connecting to 'ftp.company.com'
*** ftp connection failed: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname
Operation failed, exit code=4
```

while:

```
Node2414332# ping ftp.company.com
PING ftp.company.com (xx.yy.8.11) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ftp.company.com (xx.yy.8.11): icmp_seq=1 ttl=127 time=0.804 ms
```

**SOLVED:**

Though our python’s createconnection() fails in getaddrinfo() when given a hostname (see below), it works with an address.  Conveniently, gethostbyname() works and so we have the simple fix: createconnection(gethostbyname(hostname)).  Weerd.

Comment: This may be a better question for http://serverfault.com/

Comment: What does the output of "dig ftp.company.com ANY" look like?

Comment: Can that hostname be resolved via all the name servers in resolv.conf? (i'm assuming you're using Linux based on your prompt and pathing) Is the machine dual homed?

Comment: do you by any chance have a dash "-" in the hostname, that causes parsing of the line arguments to interpret them wrong?

Comment: @David, I've extended the question with dig output - thanks for having a go :)

Comment: @tMC, I am checking into the dual-homed thing; notes on resolv.conf added to end of Q above.

Comment: @Iliyan, nice thought, but no dashes - only [a-z].

Comment: How is the resolution done in `myftp.py`? Does it depend on the `ftplib` from the standard python distribution?

Comment: @tMC, yes, ftplib, and our Python is 2.6

Comment: any chance we can see the code that either resolves the hostname or calls to the ftplib?

Comment: @tMC, code snippet added..

Comment: Looking into the `ftplib`, it uses `socket.create_connection` to connect to the server.  Can you try opening the interactive Python interpreter and type this: `import socket;
s = socket.create_connection(('HOSTNAME_OF_FTP_SERVER', 21))`.  Does that fail?

Comment: @tMC, fails similarly: "  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/socket.py", line 498, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname"

Comment: and again: >>> socket.getaddrinfo('ftp.company.com', 21, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
socket.gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname

Comment: A straight NS resolution i would expect to see: `[Errno -2] Name or service not known`.  Im slightly stumped.  Is the hostname in internal DNS only?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.. this is on an internal development network.  ping and host both resolve name to address on the same machine as the python getaddrinfo() fails.  I've been careful to ensure there is no whitespace around the host or domain names (nor characters other than [a-z]).  If I manually add a space before or after I get your [Errno -2] Name or service not known.  This is almost as if DNS is refusing to give the address to a specific app - is that possible?

Comment: Presuming you are doing this on Linux, errno -5 is I/O Error which would normally indicate a network error or permission problem. This wouldn't happen to be an SELinux environment would it? What OS is this?

Comment: SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11

Comment: Bizarrely, though our python’s createconnection fails in getaddrinfo() when given a hostname (see above), gethostbyname works and so we have the simple fix:
 createconnection(gethostbyname(hostname))